# where can i found the "print()" result in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am creating a website and trying out flutter web using Visual Studio Code. I can't find the result of calls to the `print()` method.

When we code in flutter in Android Studio, it's in Logcat, and in Visual Studio Code, it is shown in the terminal window. But for flutter web in Visual Studio code, where can I find it?

I have checked the termainal, the debug console, and all of the output windows. Also, in my browser, I've looked through the Inspect Element, the Console and Debugger windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the web developer console of the browser you are using.

Instructions on how to do that in Chrome are here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Brief instructions:

1. Open the flutter web app in browser
2. Press CTRL+SHIFT+I
3. Select the console tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on your WebSite:

[image]

Press 'Inspect'

Go to console:

[image]

Done.